# IDEA IntelliJ maven validate hangs during buildnumber git pull, CLI mvn validate works

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea, buildnumber-maven-plugin

**What am i trying to do**

Build own java jar libraries and publish them to github as maven repository. Checkout those libraries as extensions to simplify updates as i have now half a dozen projects depending on those tiny libs and updates become tedious.

**What kind of prior knowledge do i have**

This is my first experience with IntelliJ and Maven.

**Where lies the problem**

IDEA IntelliJ hangs - does never finish - during executing:

`Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git pull git@github.com:NoxMortem/mvn.git master"`

**Local file Structure**

```
.../mvn/mvn.public/
.../mvn/mvn.public/release
.../mvn/mvn.public/snapshot
.../mvn/mvn.public/.git
.../mvn/mvn.public/.idea
.../mvn/mvn.public/pom.xml
```

This shall become my local github repository which will be pushed to github. I want releases to be pushed to release and snapshots to snapshot as this is the proposed structure from one of the many maven tutorials. This is **not** the maven project i am trying to validate!

```
.../mvn/mvn.private
.../mvn/mvn.private/target
.../mvn/mvn.private/.git
.../mvn/mvn.private/.idea
.../mvn/mvn.private/pom.xml


.../mvn/mvn.private/projects
.../mvn/mvn.private/projects/LocalLogback
.../mvn/mvn.private/projects/LocalLogback/src/.....
.../mvn/mvn.private/projects/LocalLogback/pom.xml
```

This **is** the maven project/library i am currently testing my setup and trying to validate. It does only have 2 dependencies which are successfully downloaded by maven sflj4 and logback-core.

**What programs do i use and what did i already try**

1. Running Microsoft Windows 8 64 Bit
2. TortoiseGIT for PageAnt and TortoiseGitPLink
3. private SSH key is loaded to pageant
4. GIT_SSH=c:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitPLink.exe is set
5. Using IDEA IntellJ->Maven Projects->Local Logback->Lifecycle->validate

This results in the given error message.

If i try to call

`mvn validate`

in CLI the folder

`.../mvn/mvn.private/projects/LocalLogback`

then it finishes sucessfully

**How does the pom.xml from Local Logback look like**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


<groupId>at.midneid.maven.private</groupId>
<artifactId>locallogback</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Local Logback</name>
<url>http://sr.midneid.at</url>

<scm>
    <url>https://github.com/NoxMortem/mvn.git</url>
    <connection>scm:git:git://github.com/NoxMortem/mvn.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:NoxMortem/mvn.git</developerConnection>
</scm>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <email>noxmortem@midneid.at</email>
        <name>NoxMortem</name>
        <url>https://github.com/NoxMortem</url>
        <id>NoxMortem</id>
    </developer>
</developers>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <finalName>$\{project.artifactId}-$\{project.version}-r$\{buildNumber}</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-beta-9</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>../../../mvn.public</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>true</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, because I'm not using git, but why do you have intellij using `cmd.exe` to execute git, when it already has a provided/built-in git client?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the default command it uses when you do not set anything. And your question is absolutely valid!

Comment: Can you try to use the built-in client and see what happens?

Comment: I must admit I would not know how, was i don't know why it does even use not the built in client. I gave up the whole thing as for the site-github-deploy process to publish the lib to github i had to change a lot anyway as many of the maven plugins are really not easy to get running into one build process :(